# How to create an ListView without ListActivity

Tags: java, android

Someone could tell me how can I create a ListView without using a ListActivity?

I need to put in my layout several other views, and I wish the layout was not fully occupied by the ListView. It must be part of the layout, not the entire layout. I want to create a normal Activity.

Code snippet:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.savings);

        //...
        ListView lvPoupanca = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.lvPoupanca);

        // the adapter
        TestRepository repo = new TestRepository(this);

        Cursor c = repo.getCursor();

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, c, new String[]{"Nome", "ValorAtual"}, new int[] {R.id.tvNome, R.id.tvValorTotal});
        lvPoupancas.setAdapter(adapter);
    // ...

}
```

**Edit:**

The saving.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvPoupancas"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope somebody can help me.

Thanks and sorry about my bad english.

Comment: Just to explain: when this code snippet runs, nothing happens.

Comment: The interesting part is the declaration of `lvPoupancas`.

Comment: Sorry, I put the xml file now.

Answer (score 3):

Like with any other View in any Activity...

```
ListView l = new ListView(this); 
// OR
ListView l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id...);
...
l.setAdapter(...);
// If using first way: setContentView(l);
```

For example

Comment: But I need my list view on the savings.xml

Comment: Then, add it to the XML and get a reference with findViewById()

Answer (score 2):

Don't Extend ListActivity then. Extend an **Activity** and in onCreate() put the following code as per your requirement.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.ur_xml);
    Listview list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvPoupancas);
    list.setAdapter(your Adapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have replied to a similar question before. But that was in a different context. So, I'm putting some reference code here. It will help you to fix the issue.

```
public class ListandtextActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final String [] str = {"ONE","TWO","THREE"};
        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        ArrayAdapter<Object> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, str); 
        lv.setAdapter(adapt);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                tv.setText("You Clicked Something");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" android:textSize="20dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

By the way, before asking questions, collect as much information as possible for others to help you. If it does not work, it will be better to put the error log in the question rather than just saying it does not work.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this and did not work. I think there is some issue with my SimpleCursorAdapter, but i don't receive any errors on LogCat, and using Log class to debug, I can see all itens of the cursor. Everything works (no errors), but it is not binding. This issue is driving me mad, because I tried a lot on Google but could not find any solution.

Comment: Try to create a fresh project for this list stuff and see if it works. Similarly, try creating a separate project for your adapter thing. If both of them works, you would probably be able to integrate them together. Logcat should be giving you atleast some reference to what is going on when you run a program. Don't forget to pastebin the logcat when you reply. :)